# Why insert into consume less time than select

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a curiosity. I had to create a select to retrive data from a table which contains  milions of data and to add some filters. I needed the data only for a specific period between start_date and current_date. 
I needed this data to calculate some requirement.

First I tried to use the with clause to filter the data and keep only the values between the start and current date, but the running has taken a long time. (Lets say 30 seconds just to have something to compare).

After that I've created a table and insert into it using the same long running select and the insert had run in 2 seconds.

Can someone explain me why ? I want to learn how to optimize my queries and I need to understand this.

I can't post the actual query but I can sketch something.

```
SELECT
    employee_id, 
    access_date, 
    access_description, 
    day, 
    org_type, 
    access_day 
FROM 
( 
     SELECT 
        employee_id, 
        access_date, 
        access_description, 
        day, 
        org_type, 
        trunc(access_date) as access_day, 
        row_number() over partition by (employee_id, access_date order by access_date) as dedup 
    FROM employees epl 
    WHERE access_date >=to_date('01-JAN-2018','DD-MON-YYYY') 
    AND access_date <=to_date('31-JAN-2018','DD-MON-YYYY') 
    AND access_description='A1' AND day='monday' 
    AND UPPER(org_type) <>'D' AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT null FROM emp e WHERE epl.employee_id=e.employee_id  
     AND e.access_type='a') 
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT null FROM tmp t where epl.employee_id =t.employee_id) ) 
where dedup=1;
```

I have an index on employee_id. If i run this it takes around 30 seconds.

If i create a table employee_filter:

```
insert into employee_filter 
SELECT 
    employee_id, 
    access_date, 
    access_description, 
    day, 
    org_type, 
    access_day 
FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        employee_id, 
        access_date, 
        access_description, 
        day, 
        org_type, 
        trunc(access_date) as access_day, 
        row_number() over partition by (employee_id, access_date order by access_date) as dedup 
    FROM employees epl 
    WHERE access_date >=to_date('01-JAN-2018','DD-MON-YYYY') 
    AND access_date <=to_date('31-JAN-2018','DD-MON-YYYY') 
    AND access_description='A1' 
    AND day='monday' AND UPPER(org_type) <>'D' 
    AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT null FROM emp e WHERE epl.employee_id=e.employee_id AND e.access_type='a') 
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT null FROM tmp t where epl.employee_id =t.employee_id) 
    ) 
where dedup=1;
```

It runs in 2 seconds.

If i run the select without the row_number function, it also run in a few seconds ~2s. But i need the function to made a deduplication.

```
SELECT 
    employee_id, 
    access_date, 
    access_description, 
    day, 
    org_type, 
    trunc(access_date) as access_day FROM employees epl 
WHERE access_date >=to_date('01-JAN-2018','DD-MON-YYYY') 
    AND access_date <=to_date('31-JAN-2018','DD-MON-YYYY') 
    AND access_description='A1' 
    AND day='monday' 
    AND UPPER(org_type) <>'D' 
    AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT null FROM emp e WHERE epl.employee_id=e.employee_id AND e.access_type='a') 
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT null FROM tmp t where epl.employee_id =t.employee_id)  epl.employee_id=e.employee_id AND e.access_type='a') 
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT null FROM tmp t where epl.employee_id =t.employee_id);
```

Comment: Pretty much the answer to any performance question is "It depends on the query". But it sounds like you're using functions in your WHERE clause, which can cause bad performance problems in some cases. Can you post the queries and table structures (including indexes)?

Comment: Please provide the EXPLAIN PLANs for both queries.